# $p$-$V$ Diagram of a real chiller (fridge, heat pump, ...)

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, volume, carnot-cycle

I am struggling to find a $p$-$V$ Diagram of a real (not CARNOT!) heat pump. Regarding engines (diesel, otto) this seems to be an easy task but I am failing to do so for heat pumps. Could anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Look up a $pV$ diagram for a Rankine power cycle. Just reverse the cycle and it becomes a $pV$ diagram for a Rankine refrigeration cycle.

Hope this helps.